# How variables defined in __init__ of Thread module get renamed to _Thread_<variable name>

Tags: python, multithreading, name-mangling

I am going through the code of `threading` module(`<Python Home>/lib/threading.py`) on Active python 2.7.2 32 bit for Windows. In the `__init__` function of the `class Thread`, there are many variables defined:

```
self.__target = target
self.__name = str(name or _newname())
self.__args = args
self.__kwargs = kwargs
self.__daemonic = self._set_daemon()
self.__ident = None
self.__started = Event()
self.__stopped = False
self.__block = Condition(Lock())
self.__initialized = True
```

Here is how I am calling the `__init__` function of `class Thread`:-

```
class ThreadWithReturnValue(Thread):
    def __init__(self, group=None, target=None, name=None,
                 args=(), kwargs={}, Verbose=None):

        Thread.__init__(self, group, target, name, args, kwargs, Verbose)
        self._return = None
        print 'in init: ', self._Thread__target
```

I fail to understand that the variable `self._Thread__target` is not initialised anywhere in the `__init__` function of `class Thread`. But, if I print this variable in my own `__init__` function, the actual value for `self.__target` from `class Thread`'s `__init__` function is shown.

Also, I tried to edit the `threading` module and put this line as the last line of the `__init__` function of `class Thread`:-

`print 'in init of Thread class in threading: ', self._Thread__target`

Still, I could see the value being printed and the interpreter does not display me any errors. So, I tried to find any function which might be doing the renaming stuff. But, could not find it.

This is happening with all the other variables defined in the `__init__` function of `class Thread`. I want to know how the variables like `self.__target` are getting renamed to `self._Thread__target`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is called name mangling it is what happens every time a variable starts with a `__`

see : http://docs.python.org/release/1.5/tut/node67.html  and http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers

Answer (score 1):

It is built into Python.  From [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers):

> When an identifier that textually occurs in a class definition begins with two or more underscore characters and does not end in two or more underscores, it is considered a private name of that class. Private names are transformed to a longer form before code is generated for them. The transformation inserts the class name in front of the name, with leading underscores removed, and a single underscore inserted in front of the class name. For example, the identifier `__spam` occurring in a class named `Ham` will be transformed to `_Ham__spam`.